# Swift Vapor Package "Circular reference" error

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, vapor

.I'm getting a "Circular reference" error in my Vapor project's Package file, and I can't figure out why. The error appears when I add the APNS dependency (https://github.com/vapor/apns). Everything is fine without this dependency, but as soon as I add it, I get the error.

Here are all my dependencies, including the APNS one:

```
dependencies: [
        //  A server-side Swift web framework.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "4.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent.git", from: "4.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-postgres-driver.git", from: "2.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/leaf.git", from: "4.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/jwt.git", from: "4.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/apns.git", from: "3.0.0"), <=== HERE
        .package(url: "https://github.com/m-barthelemy/vapor-queues-fluent-driver.git", from: "3.0.0-beta1"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor-community/mailgun.git", from: "5.0.0")
    ],
```

Can anyone help me figure out why I'd be getting this "Circular reference" error? Or maybe describe what causes the error in the first place? Is it an issue of multiple dependencies requiring conflicting versions of the same package?

Comment: I am guessing, but most likely caused by version issues. Since `apns` introduced the problem, what are the version dependencies that `apns` has? Compare those versions with what you are specifying for the other packages.

Comment: What's the actual full error message?

Comment: @0xTim That was the entirety of the error, but it was definitely user error. Posted the "answer" below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a complete fool and idiot, and forgot the `.` in front of the APNS dependency. So my dependencies looked like this:

```
.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "4.0.0"),
.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent.git", from: "4.0.0"),
.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-postgres-driver.git", from: "2.0.0"),
.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/leaf.git", from: "4.0.0"),
.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/jwt.git", from: "4.0.0"),
package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/apns.git", from: "3.0.0"),
.package(url: "https://github.com/m-barthelemy/vapor-queues-fluent-driver.git", from: "3.0.0-beta1"),
.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor-community/mailgun.git", from: "5.0.0")
```

and somehow didn't notice it, even though I corrected it when posting this question. The error wasn't terribly clear, all it said was just "Circular reference", marked on the `let package` line, like so

[image: error screenshot]

but I deserved to be mocked by an ambiguous error.